# Grails: Difference between Author.withTransaction{} and Book.withTransaction{} if both Author and Book should be saved in that transaction

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

Grails version 3.2.9

[Grails documentation](http://docs.grails.org/3.2.9/ref/Domain%20Classes/withTransaction.html) for `withTransaction` doesn't say much what is the difference between using, say, `Author.withTransaction` and `Book.withTransaction` in case when I want to save both `Author` and `Book` domain instances in that transaction like the following:

```
Author author = Author.get(1)
Book book = Book.findByAuthor(author)

Author.withTransaction { // what if we use Book here instead of Author
    author.age = 39
    book.price = 45

    author.save(failOnError: true)
    book.save(failOnError: true)
}
```

Didn't find any other documentation explaining the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference, they both do the same thing. Every domain class is decorated with `withTransaction` which is the same transnational code. You could use `Foo.withTransaction` and not even do anything related to `Foo` and it wouldn't matter.

Comment: So the syntax is a little bit weird, it doesn't matter actually on which domain you are calling `withTransactional()` method. BTW, Is that fact mentioned somewhere in documentation that there is no any difference, or we should have guessed ? :)

Comment: @SurenAznauryan Database transactions are not associated with entities.  Transactions are associated with connections.  You can interact with as many entities/tables/rows you like within a transaction.

Comment: "So the syntax is a little bit weird, it doesn't matter actually on which domain you are calling withTransactional() method." - I don't think this has anything to do with syntax.  The syntax is exactly the same, regardless of which domain class you are invoking the method on.

Comment: The syntax is `<Some Domain Class>.withTransaction(<someClosure>)`

Comment: @JeffScottBrown "Database transactions are not associated with entities" - agree but when I see that a `static` method is available on an Entity class, first it comes to mind that the method should have a logic somehow related to that class specifically, otherwise  why is it available on that class ?

Comment: "first it comes to mind that the method should have a logic somehow related to that class specifically" - It isn't.  "otherwise why is it available on that class" - Because we needed to put the method some place.  We could have made it a static method on some class named `TransactionHelper` or whatever, but we didn't.  You would only ever call `withTransaction` if a domain class existed so hanging it there is what we did.  Could have been done differently, but it wasn't.